# Fade texture inner borders to transparent in LibGDX using openGL shaders (glsl)

Tags: opengl, libgdx, glsl, shader, blur

I'm currently working on a tile game in LibGDX and I'm trying to get a "fog of war" effect by obscuring unexplored tiles. The result I get from this is a dynamically generated black texture of the size of the screen that only covers unexplored tiles leaving the rest of the background visible. This is an example of the fog texture rendered on top of a white background:

[image: Fog texture rendered on top of a white background]

What I'm now trying to achieve is to dynamically fade the inner borders of this texture to make it look more like a fog that slowly thickens instead of just a bunch of black boxes put together on top of the background.

Googling the problem I found out I could use shaders to do this, so I tried to learn some glsl (I'm at the very start with shaders) and I came up with this shader:

VertexShader:

```
//attributes passed from openGL
attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

//variables visible from java
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

//variables shared between fragment and vertex shader
varying vec2 v_texCoord0;

void main() {

    v_texCoord0 = a_texCoord0;
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * vec4(a_position, 1f);
}
```

FragmentShader:

```
//variables shared between fragment and vertex shader
varying vec2 v_texCoord0;

//variables visible from java
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform vec2 u_textureSize;
uniform int u_length;

void main() {

    vec4 texColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord0);
    vec2 step = 1.0 / u_textureSize;

    if(texColor.a > 0) {

        int maxNearPixels = (u_length * 2 + 1) * (u_length * 2 + 1) - 1;
        for(int i = 0; i <= u_length; i++) {

            for(float j = 0; j <= u_length; j++) {

                if(i != 0 || j != 0) {

                    texColor.a -= (1 - texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord0 + vec2(step.x * float(i), step.y * float(j))).a) / float(maxNearPixels);
                    texColor.a -= (1 - texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord0 + vec2(-step.x * float(i), step.y * float(j))).a) / float(maxNearPixels);
                    texColor.a -= (1 - texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord0 + vec2(step.x * float(i), -step.y * float(j))).a) / float(maxNearPixels);
                    texColor.a -= (1 - texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord0 + vec2(-step.x * float(i), -step.y * float(j))).a) / float(maxNearPixels);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    gl_FragColor = texColor;
}
```

This is the result I got setting a length of 20:

[image: Faded fog]

So the shader I wrote kinda works, but has terrible performance cause it's O(n^2) where n is the length of the fade in pixels (so it can be very high, like 60 or even 80). It also has some problems, like that the edges are still a bit too sharp (I'd like a smother transition) and some of the angles of the border are less faded than others (I'd like to have a fade uniform everywhere).

I'm a little bit lost at this point: is there anything I can do to make it better and faster? Like I said I'm new to shaders, so: is it even the right way to use shaders?

Comment: is it always centered? Maybe you can do a radial blur?

Comment: Is the border aligned with the game's tile grid? Maybe you can render it to a texture with 1 pixel per tile, and then you get 1 tile's worth of blurring for free, and you can also do 1 entire tile per shader loop instead of just 1 pixel. Note: if you do 1 tile per pixel the texture pixels have to be rotated and stretched compared to the screen pixels so you have to work out the texture coordinates

Comment: @vtastek the fog can be of various shapes and not always centered, so i can't use radial blur

Comment: @user253751 the border is indeed aligned with the isometric grid, but if i consider an entire tile per shader loop it would result in a non-homogeneous and boxy fade, because a tile is too big for this purpose. You can see the size of a tile by looking at the shortest borders in the image. The fade i'm trying to achieve is something like a third or half the size of tile

Comment: Lets say your viewport fits 50x50 tiles, create a single channel texture in that resolution so that you have one pixel for every tile, if you now sample from the texture in tile-space(transform screen position to tile position in texture) with a linear magnification filter you get a gradient between the masked and unmasked tiles which you could then further shade using some procedural noise.

Comment: Maybe you can use trick of not blurring at all, but simply having fade texture, which you render on all borders.

Comment: @SirNiculino Each sampling point would be bilinearly interpolated because that's what the GPU does to textures when sampled in between pixels (assuming you create the texture with GL_LINEAR). So one sampling point in a tile would tell you how far away the edge was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others mentioned in the comments, instead of blurring in the screen-space, you should filter in the tile-space while potentially exploiting the GPU bilinear filtering. Let's go through it with images.

First define a texture such that each pixel corresponds to a single tile, black/white depending on the fog at that tile. Here's such a texture blown up:

[image: tile map]

After applying the screen-to-tiles coordinate transformation and sampling that texture with `GL_NEAREST` interpolation we get the blocky result similar to what you have:

```
float t = texture2D(u_tiles, M*uv).r;
gl_FragColor = vec4(t,t,t,1.0);
```

[image: nearest]

If instead of `GL_NEAREST` we switch to `GL_LINEAR`, we get a somewhat better result:

[image: linear]

This still looks a little blocky. To improve on that we can apply a `smoothstep`:

```
float t = texture2D(u_tiles, M*uv).r;
t = smoothstep(0.0, 1.0, t);
gl_FragColor = vec4(t,t,t,1.0);
```

[image: smoothstep]

Or here is a version with a linear shade-mapping function:

```
float t = texture2D(u_tiles, M*uv).r;
t = clamp((t-0.5)*1.5 + 0.5, 0.0, 1.0);
gl_FragColor = vec4(t,t,t,1.0);
```

[image: clamp]

Note: these images were generated within a gamma-correct pipeline (i.e. sRGB framebuffer enabled). This is one of those few scenarios, however, where ignoring gamma may give better results, so you're welcome to experiment.

Comment: That's a great answer, thank you! I wasn't really understanding the suggestions in the comments. I'll surely try this out and mark this as the accepted answer if I can get it working

Comment: @SirNiculino I posted the code to generate these onto shader toy: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Nt3cWf